# How do i avoid SAM build installing devDependencies

Tags: node.js, lambda, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-nodejs, sam

my current folder structure is as attached file. it's a nodejs application and we use SAM to deploy in AWS. each folder is a separate lambda function and it has devDependencies in package.json which really does not need to be bundled during SAM build. but as I understand the default behaviour of "sam build" is to install devDependencies as well. In my case this devDependcies are in the private repository so i need .npmrc file in each folder to make "sam build" command work. but i really dont need these devDependencies as we use layers and all dependencies are stored in layers in my serverless application. How do i make aws build ignore my dev dependencies?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/91qd2.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of SAM are you using? It used to be a bug with `esbuild` in older version of SAM, but should be fixed as of `1.56.0`: https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/4040